# Secrets of the Javascript Ninja listing 5.8 - return value simply thrown away?

Tags: javascript, html, return, return-value

Listing 5.8 includes the following code:

```
<button id="test">Click me</button>

<script>
    function bind(context, name) {
        return function() {
            return context[name].apply(context, arguments);
        };
    }

    var button = {
        clicked: false,
        click: function () {
            this.clicked = true;
        }
    };

    var elem = document.getElementById('test');
    var bound = bind(button, 'click');
    elem.addEventListener('click', bound, false);
</script>
```

While inspecting the variables in Chrome's debugger, I realized that the return value from

```
return context[name].apply(context, arguments);
```

was non-existent. Further, modifying the button.click function so that it returned a value ended with the same result... nothing gets done with that return value after the event handler attached to the button element is clicked.

So my question is: is there any reason for that return statement in the above line? Is there any possible use for it?

EDIT:
If the example wasn't of an event handler, I probably wouldn't have asked this question. I wish the author had included a sidebar comment about the possible uses of the return value in the example.

Comment: One use case: As an event handler, if `button.click()` returned `false`, it would cancel any default behavior (e.g., prevent navigation away from the page by `<a>`).

Comment: Well some functions might return value, which is why there is return statement over there; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: @DipenShah, that's why I modified button.click() to return a value, to verify that after it ran, the value was simply thrown away. Jonathan pointed out a possible use case if the function returned false. Are there any others?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, add an answer and I'll give you the points. Thanks!